# What should be result for -1%5 in python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a list rotation function in python. I came across with the the following code :

```
def move(p, U):
q = []
for i in range(0,len(p)):
    q.append(p[(i-U)%len(p)])

return q
```

This works perfect. But I am trying to figure out when `len(p) = 5` and `U = 1`, why should be the result of `-1 % 5 = 4` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `4`. Python `%` operator always gives you a remainder with the same sign as the second operand. Thanks [Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635608/mat)  for pointing it out.

`-1 = (5) * (-1) + 4`

Therefore, the remainder is `4`.

http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations

Answer (score 0):

`a % b` will return a number with the sign of `b`.

However, your list rotation function would be better expressed as:

```
def move(l, n):
    n = n % len(l)
    return l[n:] + l[:n]
```

Comment: Nice code. Also works when n is negative.